# Panel List Php not showing all data

Tags: php, sql, list, panel

I am trying to create a panel list that shows certain rows from my database, however when I'm trying to call it, it only shows 1 data in the row even though i limit it by 5.

Here is my script:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM updates order by id desc limit 5";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if($list=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<div class=\"container\">";
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";               
            echo "</tr>";

        echo "<div class=\"col-md-4\">";
        echo "<div class=\"panel panel-primary\">";
        echo "<div class=\"panel-heading\">Updates";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<ul class=\"list-group\">";
        echo "<li class=\"list-group-item\">";
        echo "<b><h4>{$list["updates"]}</b></h4>";
        echo "</li>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
}
        echo "</table>";
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: I you should user `while` instead `if` when fetch array

Comment: @PhuDuy when i used while it creates another panel, i need the data to be shown in 1 panel body only

Comment: You can move it to child node in table tag

Comment: @PhuDuy what do you mean? Its inside table

Comment: please update your code. I don't know exactly what you want. You shouldn't create new table in while

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are fetching only once, here:

```
if ($list=mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
```

Instead wrap this up inside a loop like this:

```
$row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($row_count <= 0)  {
    echo "No records matching your query were found.";
}
else {
    // you have results

    // panel starts here
    while ($list = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        // do some magic with your results
    }
    // panel ends here
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

I think you got the idea, now you can do the rest. If not let us know again. Happy coding!

Comment: No data is showing, in the line // do some some magic with your results, i dont know how to or what to start, im really new to php

Comment: That's just a comment placeholder, you should get your data in `$list` variable, use that to echo your result.

Comment: Its creating another panel, i only need the data to be shown in a single panel

Comment: See my comments on the code, start and end the panel tags where I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You use sql to get five data, but you use mysqli_fetch_array() function only took out a line.

error line 8;